# this template attempted to load component assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I just installed Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate trial version for completing the MVC5 tutorial by Rick Anderson, which worht doing it.
The tutorial: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/getting-started.

However, I created a blank solution first and then try to add an ASP.Net Application project, which is going to be my MVC5 tutorial project. And I got this weird message:

> Error: this template attempted to load component assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Project, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. For more information on this problem
>   and how to enable this template, please see documentation on
>   Customizing Project Templates.

But I´m not customizing, I´m just creating a project out of a built in template.

Do you know how can I solve it?

Answer (score 7):

Here is the solution:

1. In Visual Studio 2013, select Tools > Extensions and Updates
2. Check for updates. You should have the Azure SDK update available.
3. Download and install the Azure SDK. After this, everything should work fine.

If your updates are not turned on, enable your auto detection of updates in Tools > Options > Environment > Extensions.

If you have unspecified error related to E_fail(code), try this:

1. When creating a new MVC 5 application, change the framework version from 4.5.1 to 4.5, if that did not work change it to 4. Check the below image if it is not clear.

[image]

Another approach:
This is really important if you are installing **Visual Studio 2013** on un-updated **Windows 7**.

there reason i am calling out "not updated is", 
The reason that 'un-updated' matters is because Visual studio 2013 does not update the powershell that is required by VS2013 for most of the stuff.

The simple solution is to **update Powershell** to the latest version.

If you are not sure how to update powershell, you can use [this tutorial](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/06/02/weekend-scripter-install-powershell-3-0-on-windows-7.aspx).

Comment: So... surprisingly enough, downloading and installing the Azure SDK worked. However, I still feel like this is a coincidental work around to a different issue. I would be interested to see a solution that doesn't involve installing another SDK that I don't plan on using anytime in the near future.

Comment: @avi: Thank you, buddy.

Answer (score 2):

So I stumbled upon this issue as well and would like to share how I was able to resolve this problem.

**Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Online -> NGet Package Manager**: Click the download button once you have the NGet Package Manager selected. Make sure to restart your Visual Studio after you have downloaded the Manager.

This should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Close Visual Studio, run the VS executable with the command line option as shown below (you will likely have to supply the full path), and relaunch VS normally. This should re-initialize the templates, including the one that you are having problems with.

devenv.exe /installvstemplates

Comment: I open system symbol console and executed it under

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE>devenv.exe -inst
allvstemplates

nothing seem tohappened but there is a Microsoft Visual Studio dialog window that says "The Operation Could not be completed". My Windows user account has administrative priviledges

Comment: Is the space in "-inst allvstemplates" just a copy/paste typo or did you by chance input it incorrectly? When I ran it, there was a brief flash of some window opening and then immediately closing. Then I re-launched VS normally and when it launched some dialog box came up for a couple minutes. I forget what that box said but it was obvious it was doing something the duration and when it finished, the dialog closed and mine now worked. This command was suggested directly to me by a member of the VS team and it worked for me. I don't have any suggestions beyond that, sorry man.

Comment: Nope, it was typo. It just does not work. I even open power shell as admin and nothing changes, still the same mistake. :(

Comment: Try it from an elevated cmd.exe. Powershell doesn't interpret the command line arguments the same way.

Comment: Just did it, and yes, it goes in a different fashion. no error messages, but no flickering window nor waiting time when opening VS2013 again. This is the weirdest thing.

Comment: Only for divagation. This is a Windows 8 Enterprise, could there be an incompatibility?

Comment: I had the problem on Win8.1 Enterprise, it being a fresh install of the OS and VS. Sorry man, I am out of ideas.

Comment: no problem, I´ll keep looking into it anywy, if I solve it, I´ll post it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

So I faced the same problem with Visual Studio 2013, and I don't know what's the problem but it appears that it only occurs when creating a new project, and choosing "Web" from the panel.

What I did was simply clicking on "Visual Studio 2012" just below it, and it worked !

Comment: I just got time to reinstall VS again and now it orks. SO, no real knowledge of the problem yet