# Error while creating an ASP.NET project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I haven't used Visual Studio ('17) for a while, but recently I've attempted to create an ASP.NET application and received the following error in the form of a dialog. I've also noticed that the option: ASP.NET Web Application has been replaced.

> Error: this template attempted to load component assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Project, Version[equalstosign]2.3.0.0,
>   Culture[equalstosign]neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken[equalstosign]b03f5f7f11d50a30a'.For more information on
>   this problem and how to enable this template, please see documentation
>   on customizing project templates.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? How does it react to anything you did ? Like re-opening etc... ? Did you reboot ? Did you uninstall packages that Visual Studios might need ? Have you tried reinstalling or repairing your install ? If you feel lost about how to describe your problem, look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: There are already some similar questions : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20386758/this-template-attempted-to-load-component-assembly-microsoft-visualstudio-web-pr && https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30656261/error-this-template-attempted-to-load-component-assembly-microsoft-visualstudi

Comment: @Antry, yes I have tried to experiment with various .net framework versions i.e. switching from version 4.5.2 to 4.5.1.

Comment: @SydneyKhanye Changing the .net framework won't do anything anyways, it's just the target for your project, but from what I understand you can't even access it. I'd give JimmyFL's solution a go as well as everything I proposed, I'd be surprised if 1 of these procedures didn't fix you problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround for this is to edit C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config and add to the  section:

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Universal.TemplateWizards" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="14.0.0.0" newVersion="15.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.WinRT.TemplateWizards" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="14.0.0.0" newVersion="15.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Thanks mate, apparently it was caused by a node extension I had installed earlier on.

Comment: Thanks for updating me. Glad you resolved the problem =)